# Error when run simple shell script on opensuse15.1: SubEntry: number of args (2) is invalid

Tags: shell

The following error occurred every time I tried to run a simple shell script(test.sh):

> SubEntry: number of args (2) is invalid

This single line code is in the test.sh:`echo -e 'open 192.168.1.123 \nuser root pass \nput test.csv \nquit'|ftp -inv`
If I run the code line directly in the command line works OK: the file test.csv is transferred successfully via FTP on server 192.168.1.123.
Any one know why I get that error when I run the shell script?!Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution for sending files via FTP using a script.
I use curl to send the file like this:

```
curl -T your_file ftp://your_IP
```

This command can be put in a script and automatic run that script.Works for me.